# swift - how to check if an array contains nth time a string?

Tags: arrays, swift

let's take the array :

```
var myArray = ["a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b"]
```

I know that you need to use .contains() to know if the array contains an objet.
`myArray.contains("a") //true`

But how to know if the array contains 4 times "a" ?

Comment: myArray.filter{$0 == "a"}.count  chck did it work for you

Comment: @ShobhakarTiwari Please make that an answer.

Comment: @l.b.dev i added as answer , make it correct answer

Comment: @Shobhakar Tiwari

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Swift this can be find out with just a single line of code :

```
myArray.filter{$0 == "a"}.count
```

Hope it helps. Enjoy Coding

Answer (score 5):

The `filter` solution shown in other answers is neat, and fit for the purpose. I'll include a few more alternatives.

---

As another alternative, use a simple `for ... in` loop with a `where` condition holding the conditional to increase a counter:

```
let myArray = ["a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b"]
var count = 0
for element in myArray where element == "a" { count += 1 }
print(count) //4
```

Or, as another alternative, make use of `reduce`:

```
let myArray = ["a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b"]
let count = myArray.reduce(0) { $0 + ($1 == "a" ? 1 : 0) }
print(count) //4
```

I'll also include a use example for `NSCounted` set covered in [@user28434's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41225421/4573247)

```
import Foundation
let myArray = ["a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b"]
let countedSet = NSCountedSet(array: myArray)
let count = countedSet.count(for: "a")
print(count) // 4

// or, simply
let count = NSCountedSet(array: myArray).count(for: "a")
```

Comment: Simply awesome: "let count = NSCountedSet(array: myArray).count(for: "a")"

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`NSCountedSet`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nscountedset).

> ## Overview
>
> **Each distinct object inserted into an NSCountedSet object has a counter associated with it**. NSCountedSet keeps track of the number of times objects are inserted and requires that objects be removed the same number of times. Thus, there is only one instance of an object in an NSSet object even if the object has been added to the set multiple times. The count method defined by the superclass NSSet has special significance; it returns the number of distinct objects, not the total number of times objects are represented in the set. The NSSet and NSMutableSet classes are provided for static and dynamic sets, respectively, whose elements are distinct.
>
> While NSCountedSet and CFBag are not toll-free bridged, they provide similar functionality. For more information about CFBag, see the CFBag.

```
let countedSet = NSCountedSet(array: myArray)
let countOfA = countedSet.count(for: "a") // returns 4
```

Being non-generic Objective C type it will erase type though, so use it with caution.

Comment: This is a better solution than the accepted one, for cases where multiple strings will be queried from the same array

Answer (score 0):

When solving problems like this I typically use `filter` to create a new array with only the "a" elements, then simply call `count` on the new array.

```
let count = myArray.filter({$0 == "a"}).count
print("The element 'a' occurs \(count) times")
```